# Positioning SVG elements using CSS

Tags: css, svg

Assume the following svg document:

```
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<text x="20" y="20">My text</text>
</svg>
```

Now what i want to do is reposition this text using css.

I have tried adding `style="dx:20"` and `style="transform: translate(20)"`. Both have no effect in firefox and safari. Adding these as normal attributes works fine but then i can't split the positioning from the actual code.
Setting `x`, `y`, `left` and `top` in the style isn't working either.

Is there a way to position an svg element using css?

Comment: I think i'll use symbols as a decent alternative. The user needs to specify a bit more manually but at least i don't have to pass layout-stuff through my library code.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem Yorick? I was hoping to position my SVG with CSS document but the positioning is not working sadly...

Comment: Nope, never found a solution. I think David Thomas' answer is the best you will find right now.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem Yorick? I was hoping to position my animated SVG texts responsively, bu then the animations stop sadly...

Answer (score 47):

I've managed to move some SVG text in chrome using the following CSS:

```
text.identity{
transform: translate(74px,0px);
-ms-transform: translate(74px,0px); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: translate(74px,0px); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: translate(74px,0px); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: translate(74px,0px); /* Firefox */
}
```

However, it's not budging in Firefox...

Comment: I think this is one of the most expense ways I have ever seen to move text

Comment: You're right, but sadly SVG and CSS are wedded as well as we'd like right now.  If you have a faster way I'd love to see it.

Comment: As of Firefox 23, `-moz-transform` is not required; `-transform`  works fine!

Answer (score 36):

I came here looking for a fix but fixed the issue myself, thought I would share:

```
transform: translate(100px, 100px)
```

Appears to work in all modern browsers except for Internet Explorer, right up until Microsoft Edge (which isn't even out yet) which is quite disappointing. The elements I've tested on are:

```
<path>
<polygon>
<g>
```

The only issue I've had is with `<text>` elements, and the solution there is to wrap the `<text>` in a `<g>` and apply the transformation to that. That should also work for any elements I haven't yet tested that have issues with `transform: translate()`.

I haven't found a decent fallback for Internet Explorer, instead I've made sure that the transforms aren't vital to the function of the SVG.

Comment: this really saved me, i had been stumped for a few days.Thanks! If you are frustrated try this hack!

Comment: This surely works for most of SVG elements except those that we are  animating. Translating such an element prevents its animation. Atleast in all my cases.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a hacky possibility to position specifically text-elements purely by CSS, by abusing the attributes [**‘letter-spacing’**](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#LetterSpacingProperty) for the x-coordinate and [**‘baseline-shift’**](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#BaselineShiftProperty) for the y-coordinate:

```
<defs>
    <font><font-face font-family="cssPosAnchor" />
        <glyph unicode="." horiz-adv-x="0" />
    </font>
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
#cssPos {
    font-family:cssPosAnchor;
    letter-spacing:10px; /* x-coordinate */
}
#cssPos>tspan {
    font-family:serif;
    letter-spacing:normal;
    baseline-shift:-30px; /* negative y-coordinate */
}
]]>
    </style>
</defs>
<text id="cssPos">.<tspan>CSS-Positioned Text!</tspan></text>
```

**‘baseline-shift’** is only applicable on **‘tspan’** Elements, thus making the inner `<tspan>` necessary in the presented code. Positive values for baseline-shift move the text upwards, opposite of the normal direction in the svg.

**‘letter-spacing’** needs an initial letter to have an effect, thus making the `.` necessary. To eliminate the width of this first letter, we use the special made font `cssPosAnchor`, where the dot has no width and no shape. The following `<tspan>` additionally restores font and letter-spacing.

### Scope

Should work in every conforming SVG implementation.

There is one indefinite limitation though for negative x-coordinates. The specification for the ‘letter-spacing’ attribute says: “Values may be negative, but there may be implementation-specific limits.”

### Compatibility

Text **‘direction’** change should work just fine, when imposed on the inner `<tspan>`.

A non-standard **‘writing-mode’** must be imposed on the outer `<text>`. There will most certainly be problems with that.

The probably more important **‘text-anchor’** values **middle** and **end** can be made possible like this:

```
<defs>
    <font><font-face font-family="cssPosAnchor" />
        <glyph unicode="." horiz-adv-x="0" />
        <glyph unicode=" " horiz-adv-x="0" />
    </font>
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
#cssPos {
    font-family:cssPosAnchor;
    letter-spacing:100px; /* x-coordinate */
    word-spacing:-200px; /* negative double x-coordinate */
}
#cssPos>tspan {
    font-family:serif;
    word-spacing:normal;
    letter-spacing:normal;
    baseline-shift:-30px; /* negative y-coordinate */
}
#cssPos {
    text-anchor=middle;
}
]]>
    </style>
</defs>
<text id="cssPos">.<tspan>CSS-Positioned Text!</tspan> .</text>
```

The `‹space›.` before the closing `<\text>` tag produces spacing equal to minus x-coordinate. So the inner `<tspan>` is moved around but preserves it's space in the `<text>` as if it was still there.

Since there may be implementation-specific limits on negative values for the spacing attributes, this is not guaranteed to work on all clients!

Comment: Very clever trick...thanks! Note this also works with svg <text>

Answer (score 6):

At the moment, it seems -according to [Shelley Powers](http://www.alistapart.com/authors/p/shelleyp), in her [A List Apart Article](http://www.alistapart.com/) "[Using SVG for Flexible, Scalable and Fun Backgrounds: Part I](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/using-svg-for-flexible-scalable-and-fun-backgrounds-part-i/)" and "[Part II](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/using-svg-for-flexible-scalable-and-fun-backgrounds-part-ii/)"- that CSS is not currently best-suited to positioning of SVG. In fact it seems to be quite a minefield to incorporate SVG into a web-page, without directly embedding it within the html itself.

I hope that there are solutions to be found, and, indeed, Powers does offer a couple of workarounds, to enable proper separation of style and content for SVG. I'd hazard a guess that the current problems are the relative new-ness of the concept/standard (relative to, for example, `.gif` or even `.png`...), sadly.

I'm sorry I can't offer a better answer. =/

Answer (score 4):

### Use css positioning:

index.html

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><text x="20" y="20">My text</text>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000; /* bigger than your svg */
  width: 1000; /* bigger than your svg */
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;  /* relative to parent container */
  left: 10px; /* relative to parent container */
}
```

Answer (score -3):

polygon  r="7" id="map_points_55"  points="23,10 15,27 34,16 10,16 31,27" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:0;fill-rule:nonzero;"

if you want to move the star then add to 10 or more in points like points="33,20 25,37 44,26 20,26 41,37"

Answer (score -7):

I warn you i'm a relative beginner but what about "x" and "y" and assigning these with number and "px"

maybe:

```
left: 290px;    top: 1200px;
```

or

```
x:30px; y:50px;
```

and

```
text-anchor:start;
```

Sample:

```
<text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:32;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;text-align:start;line-height:125%;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;font-family:Comic Sans MS;-inkscape-font-specification:Comic Sans MS Bold"
       x="131.42857"
       y="269.50504"
       id="text2383"
       sodipodi:linespacing="125%"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan2385"
         x="131.42857"
         y="269.50504">Position ze text</tspan></text>
```

Comment: Thanks, never thought about using left and top. But these aren't working either. I have updated my question to include these.

Comment: What's the point of adding an answer without even checking if it works? (It does not.)