# Animating SVG path with a clipPath using CSS

Tags: css, animation, svg

I thought I was doing something pretty trivial; animating a masked shape within an SVG, but it has utterly confounded me.

I have a relatively simple setup: an SVG with a defined `clipPath` and a `path` that uses said mask. Statically, this works exactly as expected - the `clipPath` masks the pattern I'm using. However, I was intending to animate the `path` so that it swoops in nicely, creating a nice text effect:

[image]

The first issue I encountered was that I couldn't use `left` or `top` in CSS to manipulate the position of path. I found a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193916/positioning-svg-elements-using-css) that suggested using `transform: translate(100px, 100px);` which ostensibly seems to work. However, as soon as I move my `path`, the actual `clipMask` moves with it so that the whole thing appears off-centre.

To an extent I can *kinda* see how this might make sense, but coming from a Flash background I'm used to my masks staying still while I move the masked element.

I've set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ar5ojkkc/) to illustrate the issue, and here's a code snippet:

```css
body {
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, san-serif;
}

#helvetica {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}

#helvetica svg path#pattern {
    left: -300px;
    /*transform: translate(-300px, 0);*/
}
```

```html
<div id="helvetica">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="550" height="80" viewbox="0 0 550 80">
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="myMask">
   <path fill="#FF00CC" d="M55.7 28 L61.6 28 61.6 38.25 72.4 38.25 72.4 28 78.3 28 78.3 54.75 72.4 54.75 72.4 43.2 61.6 43.2 61.6 54.75 55.7 54.75 55.7 28 M104.6 28 L109.9 28 109.9 54.75 104.6 54.75 104.6 28 M87.75 41.25 Q87.35 42.2 87.3 43 L95.95 43 Q95.6 40.95 94.65 39.9 93.65 38.85 91.75 38.85 90.05 38.85 89.1 39.55 88.15 40.3 87.75 41.25 M91.9 34.85 Q94.35 34.85 96.2 35.8 98 36.75 99.2 38.35 100.4 39.95 100.9 42 101.45 44.1 101.3 46.35 L87.3 46.35 Q87.4 48.85 88.65 50.1 89.85 51.3 92.05 51.25 93.7 51.25 94.85 50.45 96 49.7 96.25 48.75 L100.95 48.75 Q99.8 52.15 97.5 53.7 95.2 55.3 91.9 55.3 88.8 55.25 86.6 53.95 84.4 52.7 83.2 50.4 82 48.1 82 45.05 82 42.15 83.25 39.85 84.45 37.5 86.7 36.2 88.9 34.85 91.9 34.85 M133.95 39.85 Q135.15 37.5 137.4 36.2 139.6 34.85 142.6 34.85 145.05 34.85 146.9 35.8 148.7 36.75 149.9 38.35 151.1 39.95 151.6 42 152.15 44.1 152 46.35 L138 46.35 Q138.1 48.85 139.35 50.1 140.55 51.3 142.75 51.25 144.4 51.25 145.55 50.45 146.7 49.7 146.95 48.75 L151.65 48.75 Q150.5 52.15 148.2 53.7 145.9 55.3 142.6 55.3 139.5 55.25 137.3 53.95 135.1 52.7 133.9 50.4 132.7 48.1 132.7 45.05 132.7 42.15 133.95 39.85 M139.8 39.55 Q138.85 40.3 138.45 41.25 138.05 42.2 138 43 L146.65 43 Q146.3 40.95 145.35 39.9 144.35 38.85 142.45 38.85 140.75 38.85 139.8 39.55 M126.1 35.35 L131.4 35.35 124.85 54.75 118.9 54.75 112.3 35.35 117.85 35.35 121.95 48.6 122 48.6 126.1 35.35 M178.6 39.9 Q179.75 37.55 181.95 36.2 184.15 34.85 187.35 34.85 189.65 34.85 191.65 35.65 193.65 36.45 194.95 38.05 196.25 39.7 196.45 42.2 L191.25 42.2 Q191 40.55 189.95 39.7 188.95 38.85 187.3 38.85 185.6 38.85 184.6 39.85 183.6 40.8 183.2 42.25 182.75 43.7 182.75 45.15 182.75 46.6 183.15 48 183.6 49.35 184.55 50.3 185.5 51.25 187.2 51.25 189.05 51.25 190.1 50.2 191.15 49.15 191.4 47.35 L196.55 47.35 Q196 51.2 193.55 53.25 191.1 55.25 187.2 55.3 184.3 55.25 182.1 54 179.9 52.75 178.65 50.5 177.45 48.25 177.45 45.35 177.45 42.3 178.6 39.9 M168.5 28 L173.8 28 173.8 32.35 168.5 32.35 168.5 28 M168.5 35.35 L173.8 35.35 173.8 54.75 168.5 54.75 168.5 35.35 M165.75 35.35 L165.75 38.95 161.85 38.95 161.85 48.5 Q161.85 49.85 162.3 50.3 162.8 50.8 164.1 50.8 L164.95 50.75 165.75 50.65 165.75 54.8 164.25 54.95 162.65 54.95 159.6 54.65 Q158.25 54.25 157.4 53.25 156.55 52.3 156.55 50.35 L156.55 38.95 153.3 38.95 153.3 35.35 156.55 35.35 156.55 29.55 161.85 29.55 161.85 35.35 165.75 35.35 M238.75 43.7 L227.55 43.7 227.55 54.75 221.65 54.75 221.65 28 240.45 28 240.45 32.9 227.55 32.9 227.55 39.1 238.75 39.1 238.75 43.7 M204.95 47.2 Q204.05 47.8 204 49.25 204.05 50.7 205 51.2 205.95 51.75 207.3 51.7 208.85 51.7 209.7 51.2 L211 49.9 211.5 48.45 211.6 47.25 211.6 45.25 Q210.9 45.8 209.65 46 L207.15 46.4 Q205.9 46.6 204.95 47.2 M204.2 35.4 L208.4 34.85 211.4 35.05 Q212.85 35.25 214.15 35.85 215.35 36.45 216.15 37.5 216.9 38.6 216.95 40.35 L216.95 50.45 217.05 52.95 Q217.25 54.15 217.6 54.75 L212.2 54.75 211.95 53.85 211.8 52.9 Q210.55 54.2 208.8 54.75 L205.3 55.3 Q203.45 55.3 201.95 54.65 200.45 54.05 199.6 52.75 198.7 51.45 198.7 49.45 198.75 47.3 199.65 46.1 200.6 44.9 202.1 44.35 203.6 43.75 205.3 43.6 L208.4 43.2 210.7 42.55 Q211.6 42.1 211.6 41 211.6 39.9 211.1 39.35 210.65 38.75 209.9 38.55 L208.15 38.4 Q206.6 38.4 205.7 39.1 204.75 39.75 204.6 41.35 L199.3 41.35 Q199.5 38.85 200.8 37.45 202.15 36 204.2 35.4 M275.4 28 L280.7 28 280.7 54.75 275.4 54.75 275.4 28 M265.7 28 L271 28 271 54.75 265.7 54.75 265.7 28 M256.2 35.35 L261.5 35.35 261.5 54.75 256.45 54.75 256.45 52.05 256.35 52.05 Q255.3 53.7 253.7 54.5 252.15 55.3 250.4 55.3 247.6 55.25 246.05 54.25 244.5 53.3 243.9 51.5 243.3 49.7 243.35 47.3 L243.35 35.35 248.65 35.35 248.65 46.35 Q248.65 48.7 249.45 49.9 250.25 51.1 252.05 51.1 254.25 51.1 255.2 49.8 256.2 48.45 256.2 45.55 L256.2 35.35 M315.95 35.35 L319.85 35.35 319.85 38.95 315.95 38.95 315.95 48.5 Q315.95 49.85 316.4 50.3 316.9 50.8 318.2 50.8 L319.05 50.75 319.85 50.65 319.85 54.8 318.35 54.95 316.75 54.95 313.7 54.65 Q312.35 54.25 311.5 53.25 310.65 52.3 310.65 50.35 L310.65 38.95 307.4 38.95 307.4 35.35 310.65 35.35 310.65 29.55 315.95 29.55 315.95 35.35 M294.65 27.35 Q297.5 27.3 299.95 28.2 302.35 29.1 303.85 31 305.35 32.9 305.4 35.95 L299.7 35.95 Q299.6 34.35 298.85 33.45 298.15 32.6 297 32.25 L294.4 31.9 292.5 32.2 Q291.6 32.5 291 33.15 290.35 33.85 290.35 34.95 290.3 35.95 290.9 36.55 291.55 37.1 293.25 37.65 L298.35 39 300.4 39.55 Q301.7 39.95 303.05 40.8 304.4 41.65 305.3 43.1 306.25 44.55 306.3 46.8 306.3 49.3 305 51.2 303.75 53.15 301.25 54.25 298.8 55.35 295.15 55.4 292.9 55.4 290.85 54.8 288.8 54.25 287.2 53.1 285.6 51.95 284.65 50.15 283.75 48.35 283.75 45.85 L289.45 45.85 Q289.45 47.65 290.3 48.75 291.1 49.8 292.45 50.3 L295.35 50.8 297.65 50.55 Q298.85 50.3 299.7 49.55 300.55 48.85 300.6 47.5 300.55 46.05 299.4 45.3 298.25 44.5 296.45 44 L292.65 43.05 288.8 41.75 Q287 40.9 285.85 39.4 284.7 37.9 284.65 35.45 284.65 33.4 285.5 31.85 286.4 30.35 287.85 29.35 289.3 28.35 291.05 27.85 L294.65 27.35 M350.5 45.1 Q350.45 46.7 350.9 48.1 351.35 49.5 352.4 50.35 353.4 51.25 355.1 51.25 356.85 51.25 357.85 50.35 358.9 49.5 359.3 48.1 359.75 46.7 359.7 45.1 359.75 43.55 359.3 42.1 358.85 40.7 357.8 39.75 356.8 38.85 355.05 38.85 353.35 38.85 352.35 39.75 351.3 40.65 350.9 42.1 350.45 43.5 350.5 45.1 M356.25 34.85 Q359.25 34.85 361.25 36.3 363.2 37.75 364.1 40.1 365.05 42.45 365.05 45.25 365.05 47.9 364.1 50.15 363.15 52.4 361.25 53.85 359.4 55.25 356.55 55.3 354.8 55.3 353.25 54.55 351.7 53.8 350.75 52.35 L350.65 52.35 350.65 61.6 345.35 61.6 345.35 35.35 350.4 35.35 350.4 37.85 350.5 37.85 Q351.45 36.3 352.95 35.55 354.45 34.85 356.25 34.85 M327.15 45.1 Q327.15 46.65 327.6 48.05 328 49.45 329 50.35 330.05 51.25 331.85 51.25 333.65 51.25 334.7 50.35 335.75 49.45 336.15 48.05 336.6 46.65 336.55 45.1 336.6 43.5 336.15 42.1 335.75 40.65 334.7 39.75 333.65 38.85 331.85 38.85 330.05 38.85 329 39.75 328 40.65 327.6 42.1 327.15 43.5 327.15 45.1 M326.55 36.1 Q328.8 34.85 331.85 34.85 334.9 34.85 337.15 36.1 339.4 37.35 340.65 39.65 341.9 41.95 341.9 45.1 341.9 48.2 340.65 50.45 339.4 52.75 337.15 54 334.9 55.25 331.85 55.3 328.8 55.25 326.55 54 324.3 52.75 323.05 50.45 321.85 48.2 321.85 45.1 321.85 41.95 323.05 39.65 324.3 37.35 326.55 36.1 M368.5 49 L374.4 49 374.4 54.75 368.5 54.75 368.5 49"/>
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
 
 <path id="pattern" clip-path="url(#myMask)" fill="#333333" d="M493.35 13.9 L450.6 66.4 446.1 66.4 488.85 13.9 493.35 13.9 M488.1 66.4 L483.6 66.4 526.35 13.9 530.85 13.9 488.1 66.4 M455.85 13.9 L413.1 66.4 408.6 66.4 451.35 13.9 455.85 13.9 M470.85 13.9 L428.1 66.4 423.6 66.4 466.35 13.9 470.85 13.9 M431.1 13.9 L388.35 66.4 383.85 66.4 426.6 13.9 431.1 13.9 M425.85 13.9 L383.1 66.4 378.6 66.4 421.35 13.9 425.85 13.9 M437.1 13.9 L394.35 66.4 389.85 66.4 432.6 13.9 437.1 13.9 M444.6 13.9 L401.85 66.4 397.35 66.4 440.1 13.9 444.6 13.9 M377.85 66.4 L14.15 66.4 56.9 13.9 420.6 13.9 377.85 66.4"/>
 
   </svg>
</div>

<p>
    Uncomment the <code>transform</code> line in the CSS to see the effect - the mask moves <em>with</em> the masked shape.
</p>
```

Is there another way to achieve the same effect? Note that this will be placed over a photographic image, so an animated GIF isn't going to cut it, and it must be scalable without loss of quality (hence, SVG).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the clip to move, all you have to do is put it on something that doesn't move.

```css
body {
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, san-serif;
}

#helvetica {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}

#helvetica svg path#pattern {
    left: -300px;
    transform: translate(-300px, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="helvetica">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="550" height="80" viewbox="0 0 550 80">
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="myMask">
   <path fill="#FF00CC" d="M55.7 28 L61.6 28 61.6 38.25 72.4 38.25 72.4 28 78.3 28 78.3 54.75 72.4 54.75 72.4 43.2 61.6 43.2 61.6 54.75 55.7 54.75 55.7 28 M104.6 28 L109.9 28 109.9 54.75 104.6 54.75 104.6 28 M87.75 41.25 Q87.35 42.2 87.3 43 L95.95 43 Q95.6 40.95 94.65 39.9 93.65 38.85 91.75 38.85 90.05 38.85 89.1 39.55 88.15 40.3 87.75 41.25 M91.9 34.85 Q94.35 34.85 96.2 35.8 98 36.75 99.2 38.35 100.4 39.95 100.9 42 101.45 44.1 101.3 46.35 L87.3 46.35 Q87.4 48.85 88.65 50.1 89.85 51.3 92.05 51.25 93.7 51.25 94.85 50.45 96 49.7 96.25 48.75 L100.95 48.75 Q99.8 52.15 97.5 53.7 95.2 55.3 91.9 55.3 88.8 55.25 86.6 53.95 84.4 52.7 83.2 50.4 82 48.1 82 45.05 82 42.15 83.25 39.85 84.45 37.5 86.7 36.2 88.9 34.85 91.9 34.85 M133.95 39.85 Q135.15 37.5 137.4 36.2 139.6 34.85 142.6 34.85 145.05 34.85 146.9 35.8 148.7 36.75 149.9 38.35 151.1 39.95 151.6 42 152.15 44.1 152 46.35 L138 46.35 Q138.1 48.85 139.35 50.1 140.55 51.3 142.75 51.25 144.4 51.25 145.55 50.45 146.7 49.7 146.95 48.75 L151.65 48.75 Q150.5 52.15 148.2 53.7 145.9 55.3 142.6 55.3 139.5 55.25 137.3 53.95 135.1 52.7 133.9 50.4 132.7 48.1 132.7 45.05 132.7 42.15 133.95 39.85 M139.8 39.55 Q138.85 40.3 138.45 41.25 138.05 42.2 138 43 L146.65 43 Q146.3 40.95 145.35 39.9 144.35 38.85 142.45 38.85 140.75 38.85 139.8 39.55 M126.1 35.35 L131.4 35.35 124.85 54.75 118.9 54.75 112.3 35.35 117.85 35.35 121.95 48.6 122 48.6 126.1 35.35 M178.6 39.9 Q179.75 37.55 181.95 36.2 184.15 34.85 187.35 34.85 189.65 34.85 191.65 35.65 193.65 36.45 194.95 38.05 196.25 39.7 196.45 42.2 L191.25 42.2 Q191 40.55 189.95 39.7 188.95 38.85 187.3 38.85 185.6 38.85 184.6 39.85 183.6 40.8 183.2 42.25 182.75 43.7 182.75 45.15 182.75 46.6 183.15 48 183.6 49.35 184.55 50.3 185.5 51.25 187.2 51.25 189.05 51.25 190.1 50.2 191.15 49.15 191.4 47.35 L196.55 47.35 Q196 51.2 193.55 53.25 191.1 55.25 187.2 55.3 184.3 55.25 182.1 54 179.9 52.75 178.65 50.5 177.45 48.25 177.45 45.35 177.45 42.3 178.6 39.9 M168.5 28 L173.8 28 173.8 32.35 168.5 32.35 168.5 28 M168.5 35.35 L173.8 35.35 173.8 54.75 168.5 54.75 168.5 35.35 M165.75 35.35 L165.75 38.95 161.85 38.95 161.85 48.5 Q161.85 49.85 162.3 50.3 162.8 50.8 164.1 50.8 L164.95 50.75 165.75 50.65 165.75 54.8 164.25 54.95 162.65 54.95 159.6 54.65 Q158.25 54.25 157.4 53.25 156.55 52.3 156.55 50.35 L156.55 38.95 153.3 38.95 153.3 35.35 156.55 35.35 156.55 29.55 161.85 29.55 161.85 35.35 165.75 35.35 M238.75 43.7 L227.55 43.7 227.55 54.75 221.65 54.75 221.65 28 240.45 28 240.45 32.9 227.55 32.9 227.55 39.1 238.75 39.1 238.75 43.7 M204.95 47.2 Q204.05 47.8 204 49.25 204.05 50.7 205 51.2 205.95 51.75 207.3 51.7 208.85 51.7 209.7 51.2 L211 49.9 211.5 48.45 211.6 47.25 211.6 45.25 Q210.9 45.8 209.65 46 L207.15 46.4 Q205.9 46.6 204.95 47.2 M204.2 35.4 L208.4 34.85 211.4 35.05 Q212.85 35.25 214.15 35.85 215.35 36.45 216.15 37.5 216.9 38.6 216.95 40.35 L216.95 50.45 217.05 52.95 Q217.25 54.15 217.6 54.75 L212.2 54.75 211.95 53.85 211.8 52.9 Q210.55 54.2 208.8 54.75 L205.3 55.3 Q203.45 55.3 201.95 54.65 200.45 54.05 199.6 52.75 198.7 51.45 198.7 49.45 198.75 47.3 199.65 46.1 200.6 44.9 202.1 44.35 203.6 43.75 205.3 43.6 L208.4 43.2 210.7 42.55 Q211.6 42.1 211.6 41 211.6 39.9 211.1 39.35 210.65 38.75 209.9 38.55 L208.15 38.4 Q206.6 38.4 205.7 39.1 204.75 39.75 204.6 41.35 L199.3 41.35 Q199.5 38.85 200.8 37.45 202.15 36 204.2 35.4 M275.4 28 L280.7 28 280.7 54.75 275.4 54.75 275.4 28 M265.7 28 L271 28 271 54.75 265.7 54.75 265.7 28 M256.2 35.35 L261.5 35.35 261.5 54.75 256.45 54.75 256.45 52.05 256.35 52.05 Q255.3 53.7 253.7 54.5 252.15 55.3 250.4 55.3 247.6 55.25 246.05 54.25 244.5 53.3 243.9 51.5 243.3 49.7 243.35 47.3 L243.35 35.35 248.65 35.35 248.65 46.35 Q248.65 48.7 249.45 49.9 250.25 51.1 252.05 51.1 254.25 51.1 255.2 49.8 256.2 48.45 256.2 45.55 L256.2 35.35 M315.95 35.35 L319.85 35.35 319.85 38.95 315.95 38.95 315.95 48.5 Q315.95 49.85 316.4 50.3 316.9 50.8 318.2 50.8 L319.05 50.75 319.85 50.65 319.85 54.8 318.35 54.95 316.75 54.95 313.7 54.65 Q312.35 54.25 311.5 53.25 310.65 52.3 310.65 50.35 L310.65 38.95 307.4 38.95 307.4 35.35 310.65 35.35 310.65 29.55 315.95 29.55 315.95 35.35 M294.65 27.35 Q297.5 27.3 299.95 28.2 302.35 29.1 303.85 31 305.35 32.9 305.4 35.95 L299.7 35.95 Q299.6 34.35 298.85 33.45 298.15 32.6 297 32.25 L294.4 31.9 292.5 32.2 Q291.6 32.5 291 33.15 290.35 33.85 290.35 34.95 290.3 35.95 290.9 36.55 291.55 37.1 293.25 37.65 L298.35 39 300.4 39.55 Q301.7 39.95 303.05 40.8 304.4 41.65 305.3 43.1 306.25 44.55 306.3 46.8 306.3 49.3 305 51.2 303.75 53.15 301.25 54.25 298.8 55.35 295.15 55.4 292.9 55.4 290.85 54.8 288.8 54.25 287.2 53.1 285.6 51.95 284.65 50.15 283.75 48.35 283.75 45.85 L289.45 45.85 Q289.45 47.65 290.3 48.75 291.1 49.8 292.45 50.3 L295.35 50.8 297.65 50.55 Q298.85 50.3 299.7 49.55 300.55 48.85 300.6 47.5 300.55 46.05 299.4 45.3 298.25 44.5 296.45 44 L292.65 43.05 288.8 41.75 Q287 40.9 285.85 39.4 284.7 37.9 284.65 35.45 284.65 33.4 285.5 31.85 286.4 30.35 287.85 29.35 289.3 28.35 291.05 27.85 L294.65 27.35 M350.5 45.1 Q350.45 46.7 350.9 48.1 351.35 49.5 352.4 50.35 353.4 51.25 355.1 51.25 356.85 51.25 357.85 50.35 358.9 49.5 359.3 48.1 359.75 46.7 359.7 45.1 359.75 43.55 359.3 42.1 358.85 40.7 357.8 39.75 356.8 38.85 355.05 38.85 353.35 38.85 352.35 39.75 351.3 40.65 350.9 42.1 350.45 43.5 350.5 45.1 M356.25 34.85 Q359.25 34.85 361.25 36.3 363.2 37.75 364.1 40.1 365.05 42.45 365.05 45.25 365.05 47.9 364.1 50.15 363.15 52.4 361.25 53.85 359.4 55.25 356.55 55.3 354.8 55.3 353.25 54.55 351.7 53.8 350.75 52.35 L350.65 52.35 350.65 61.6 345.35 61.6 345.35 35.35 350.4 35.35 350.4 37.85 350.5 37.85 Q351.45 36.3 352.95 35.55 354.45 34.85 356.25 34.85 M327.15 45.1 Q327.15 46.65 327.6 48.05 328 49.45 329 50.35 330.05 51.25 331.85 51.25 333.65 51.25 334.7 50.35 335.75 49.45 336.15 48.05 336.6 46.65 336.55 45.1 336.6 43.5 336.15 42.1 335.75 40.65 334.7 39.75 333.65 38.85 331.85 38.85 330.05 38.85 329 39.75 328 40.65 327.6 42.1 327.15 43.5 327.15 45.1 M326.55 36.1 Q328.8 34.85 331.85 34.85 334.9 34.85 337.15 36.1 339.4 37.35 340.65 39.65 341.9 41.95 341.9 45.1 341.9 48.2 340.65 50.45 339.4 52.75 337.15 54 334.9 55.25 331.85 55.3 328.8 55.25 326.55 54 324.3 52.75 323.05 50.45 321.85 48.2 321.85 45.1 321.85 41.95 323.05 39.65 324.3 37.35 326.55 36.1 M368.5 49 L374.4 49 374.4 54.75 368.5 54.75 368.5 49"/>
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
 
<g clip-path="url(#myMask)">
 <path  id="pattern" fill="#333333" d="M493.35 13.9 L450.6 66.4 446.1 66.4 488.85 13.9 493.35 13.9 M488.1 66.4 L483.6 66.4 526.35 13.9 530.85 13.9 488.1 66.4 M455.85 13.9 L413.1 66.4 408.6 66.4 451.35 13.9 455.85 13.9 M470.85 13.9 L428.1 66.4 423.6 66.4 466.35 13.9 470.85 13.9 M431.1 13.9 L388.35 66.4 383.85 66.4 426.6 13.9 431.1 13.9 M425.85 13.9 L383.1 66.4 378.6 66.4 421.35 13.9 425.85 13.9 M437.1 13.9 L394.35 66.4 389.85 66.4 432.6 13.9 437.1 13.9 M444.6 13.9 L401.85 66.4 397.35 66.4 440.1 13.9 444.6 13.9 M377.85 66.4 L14.15 66.4 56.9 13.9 420.6 13.9 377.85 66.4"/>
</g>
 
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Gah - thank you! I'd tried all kinds of combinations with `<g>` tags (since I'd read it doesn't actually 'occupy space' in an SVG), but my mistake was applying the ID I was trying to animate to the _group_ rather than leaving it on the _path_. Accepted!