# How to position elements within an SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to position two SVG g elements to be side by side. Currently, they overlap like so:

[image]
This is a class for the map legend, called "legend_container"
[image]
This is a class for the map itself, called "region"

Both are children of "Map_Container"

Here is the CSS code I'm using:

```
.Map_Container {
text-align: center;
vertical-align: top;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}

g.region {
float: right;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}

g.legend_container {
float: left;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Make your container bigger?

Comment: Tried setting map_container to 2000px width and legend_container to 200px width, but it just made the container huge and everything still overlaps in the same way.

Comment: if they're both inside the same SVG then you need to, as @zgood said, make the container bigger and set the x and y values of each. Or if they're separate containers, i.e: a div holding the map and a div holding the legend, just float left and right. You can't use float on SVG, but you can use translate. See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193916/positioning-svg-elements-using-css

Comment: is there an easy way to do the transform on the container instead of on each individual svg element? That seems like a mess